# Call a javascript method with PHP variables as parameters,

Tags: php, javascript

Let's say you have a `Javascript` function like this :

```
function foo(param1,param2)
{
//some code here
}
```

`param1` and `param2` are stored in `myDatabase`.

It's my `page.php` that requests `myDatabase` to extract `param1` and `param2`, then it stores them as `PHP` variables `$param1` and `$param2`.

How to convert `$param1` and `$param2` from `PHP` to `Javascript` so i can call my function.

```
<div onClick="foo(param1,param2)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you had this in mind:

```
<div onClick="foo(<?php echo $param1 ?>,(<?php echo $param2 ?>)"></div>
```

In case $param1 and $param2 should be string, array or object then you chould use json_encode before echoing:

```
<div onClick="foo(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($param1)) ?>,(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($param2)) ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: along with json_encode, htmlspecialchars should be used so it wont break html

Answer (score 2):

In you PHP file if `$param1` is an integer and `$param2` is a string you write

```
echo "<div onclick=\"foo($param1, '$param2')\"></div>";
```

Comment: you cannot use " inside this html attribute value. Either use ' or entity &quot;

Comment: @IvanHušnjak - I had noticed that and was in the process of fixing it.

Comment: What about Arrays and Objects?

Answer (score 1):

You must print those PHP variable values to the page, so JavaScript can access them.

Like this:

```
<script>

var param1 = <?= json_encode( $param1 ) ?>;
var param2 = <?= json_encode( $param2 ) ?>;


... other code ...

</script>
```

`json_encode()` is used to add quotes, escape quotes in strings etc.
Without it, your php string could break the javascript syntax.

Comment: So if i use `json_encode()` on PHP `Arrays` and `Objects`, then they will correct Javascript `Arrays` and `Objects`?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what you mean by `Object`, but I know they work good for arrays and associative arrays. Maybe objects too.

Comment: `class A {public $foo = 1;}
$a=new A();`

Is `json_encode($a)` going to return something like this:

`var a 
{
foo:1
}`

?

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
 var simple ='<?php echo $sparam1; ?>';
```

and then pass in parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
<div onClick="foo('<?php echo $param1 ?>', '<?php echo $param2 ?>')"></div>
```

Make sure you use single and double quotes properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div onClick="foo('<?= $param1; ?>','<?= $param2; ?>')"></div>
```